# SVG Mask and animation on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I'm not that good with SVG and mask and I would like to know if it's possible to have this animation on mouse hover? (with jquery or without)
What I need:
-Html text
-SVG 3/4 circle
-The background is the div background
If it's not possible with html text, it would probably be possible with curve text in the svg...

Here is an image of what I want to achieve:

[image: Button I want to achieve]

Comment: Create a mask, fill it with black (in mask, this prevents anything from being rendered at all), then in the mask insert pure white where you want to allow drawing. Now reference that mask when inserting (in your case blue) shapes or text. You could even make multiple versions of the mask, each starting black then applying the white text and semi-circle then applying black again to erase less and less of the white. Animate by swapping out the various masks to incrementally show more and more blue.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have a small exemple with animation? I can do a lot of stuff with css or Php, but SVG, mask and animation are not my power...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't find your font, didn't use math to be precise.

```js
var wipe_steps = [
  [1000, "0,0 500,0 500,500 0,500"],
  [100,  "250,250 0,200 0,0 500,0 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 0,100 0,0 500,0 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 0,0 500,0 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 100,0 500,0 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 200,0 500,0 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 250,0 500,0 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 300,0 500,0 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 400,0 500,0 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 500,0 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 500,100 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 500,200 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 500,250 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 500,300 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 500,400 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 500,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 400,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 300,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 250,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 200,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 100,500 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 0,500 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 0,400 0,250"],
  [100,  "250,250 0,300 0,250"],
  [3000,  ""]
];
var wipe_step = 0;

function wipe() {
  wipe_step = wipe_step % wipe_steps.length;
  $('#wiper').attr('points', wipe_steps[wipe_step][1]);
  setTimeout(wipe, wipe_steps[wipe_step++][0]);
}

wipe();
```

```css
#animation {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animation">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
      <mask id="mising_quad" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500"  maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="white" />
        <rect x="0" y="250" width="250" height="250" fill="black" />
      </mask>
      <mask id="radial_wipe_mask" x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="white" />
        <rect x="0" y="250" width="250" height="250" fill="black" />
        <rect x="100" y="250" width="150" height="100" fill="white" />
        <polygon id="wiper" points="" fill="black" />
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="rgb(230, 230, 230)" />
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="200" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="20" mask="url(#mising_quad)" />
    <text x="100" y="210" fill="white" font-family="'Lucida Bright',Georgia,serif" font-size="45" font-weight="bold">MESSAGES
      <tspan x="100" y="270">AUX MEMBRES</tspan>
      <tspan x="100" y="330">SOCI&Eacute;TAIRES</tspan>
    </text>
    <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="200" fill="none" stroke="rgb(27, 125, 189)" stroke-width="20" mask="url(#radial_wipe_mask)" />
    <text x="100" y="210" fill="rgb(27, 125, 189)" font-family="'Lucida Bright',Georgia,serif" font-size="45" font-weight="bold" mask="url(#radial_wipe_mask)">MESSAGES
      <tspan x="100" y="270">AUX MEMBRES</tspan>
      <tspan x="100" y="330">SOCI&Eacute;TAIRES</tspan>
    </text>
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You rock! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I try to change the speed, thought that the setTimeout was here for that, but finally it seems it's here more for the drawing... So how do you change the speedof the wiper? :)

Comment: @user2883964 In the wipe_steps array, the first element is the delay in milliseconds for that "frame". You could replace the 1000 with a variable like "start_delay", all the 100s with a variable "animation_speed", and the 3000 with "final_pause". Then it would be simple to read the code AND to change the animation speed. You're familiar with JavaScript variables, yes?

Comment: Yes thanks! It was to find what is for what in all those number! ;)

Comment: Ouch, I tried to change the starting point of the animation but I can't figure it out! I don't understand what coordinate is for what, guess svg coordinate are too hot for me!
Also I wanted to change the size, if I understand well all coordinate are based on "500", so if I chane the size of the animation (let's say 228px x 228px), I will have to calculate all new coordinate relative to 500 and 228...
I made a codepen with everything... http://codepen.io/dantahoua/pen/VamdKB

Comment: @Dantahoua You have a couple of issues = ). First, notice what happens when you move your mouse to the images again and again. They speed up. Can you see why? ;-) Too many hover calls. Second, if you want all the animations to be the same, you don't need multiple wipe_steps. Instead, try `$('#wiper,#wiper2,#wiper3').attr('points', wipe_steps[wipe_step][1]);`. Lastly, I think CSS will be able to shrink for you. Try: `svg { width: 228px; height: 228px; }`, but test in all browsers you care about.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried another way using Snap.svg library, here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/dantahoua/pen/ZWBVMY

Comment: @Dantahoua Wow! Nice progress! SVG groups, smooth curves, on-hover and on-away! May I suggest one final touch? If you change the white to red, notice that the aliasing causes some red to show behind the blue. With its own mask, I bet you could easily animate the white disappearing as the blue appears. Again, fantastic job! You're probably ready to teach an SVG class now!

Comment: Thanks! Yes I noticed the aliasing problem and I can't find a solution. For the circle I just added 1 point to the stroke but for the text I can't find a solution. As you said, maybe removing the text at the end of the animation or making it fade out and then fade in when the animation is reversed...

Comment: Add this mask: `<mask id="WipeUnMask"><circle id="CircleUnMask" cx="112" cy="112" r="57" fill="none" stroke="white" style="stroke-width: 114px; stroke-dasharray: 0px, 600px, 600px, 0px; stroke-dashoffset: 600px;"></circle></mask>`. Then have your white text use it: `mask="url(#WipeUnMask)"`. Rotate: `var unMask = t.select("#CircleUnMask");unMask.transform('r180');`. Lastly, animate by putting this after each bigC.attr call: `unMask.attr({'strokeDashoffset': value})`

Comment: @Dantahoua Just realized that I forgot to tag you in my last comment. Figured out some small changes to fix the white behind the blue. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working great! I really thank you! If you lived near Quebec city, I'll sure pay you a beer!

Comment: @Dantahoua Glad you're happy with the result! I learned from this question as well, so we're even. Unless I have to move to Canada after the US Elections, then I really could use a beer... Cheers! = )